# Does my question about EntityFieldQuery and destruction of it's instances belong on StackOverflow?

Tags: support

I posted a question about the EF API : [Do I need to manually destroy the EntityFieldQuery object?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/27719/2384) - and one the commentators claimed this does not belong on the Drupal site. Since it is a user with 18k reputation, I am taking that into consideration. Does it need to be migrated to Stack Overflow?

Comment: Change the question title to: "Does the Drupal API automatically release resources for an EntityFieldQuery object?" and you'll be asking exactly the same question, but without any doubt it's specific to Drupal :)

Answer (score 4):

There's [Respect the community – your own, and others’](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/) which touches on this subject:

> As members of a community, your first loyalty should be to *that* community. When evaluating a question, you shouldn’t be looking to push it off on some other site; instead, ask if it could be appropriate and on-topic for you, the experts who the author decided to ask. **Be a bit jealous of your site** – don’t blithely turn askers away simply because their question could be asked somewhere else. Don’t hit them over the head with your scope, help them tailor their question to fit into it – and if that means your site’s scope overlaps a bit with another site’s, so be it.

Because of the amount of Drupalisms out there, it's hard sometimes to determine when you can generic PHP and when you have to do something in a Drupal-specific way.

In general, unless it's a blindingly obvious PHP question (*How do I set a value to a variable?*), if a question is asking about a Drupal-specific API and how to use said API correctly, *Drupal Answers* should give the benefit of the doubt.